error: package `solana-program v1.18.26` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer,
root@d51a1db5c2a8:/# ls
bin  boot  dev  etc  home  lib  lib32  lib64  media  mnt  my_token_swap  opt  proc  root  run  sbin  srv  sys  tmp  usr  var
root@d51a1db5c2a8:/# cd my_token_swap/
root@d51a1db5c2a8:/my_token_swap# anchor build
error: package `solana-program v1.18.26` cannot be built because it requires rustc 1.75.0 or newer, while the currently active rustc version is 1.68.0-dev
Either upgrade to rustc 1.75.0 or newer, or use
cargo update -p solana-program@1.18.26 --precise ver
where `ver` is the latest version of `solana-program` supporting rustc 1.68.0-dev
root@d51a1db5c2a8:/my_token_swap# ls
Anchor.toml  Cargo.lock  Cargo.toml  app  migrations  node_modules  package.json  programs  target  tests  tsconfig.json  yarn.lock
root@d51a1db5c2a8:/my_token_swap# cat Cargo.toml
[workspace]
members = [
    "programs/*"
]
resolver = "2"

[profile.release]
overflow-checks = true
lto = "fat"
codegen-units = 1
[profile.release.build-override]
opt-level = 3
incremental = false
codegen-units = 1
root@d51a1db5c2a8:/my_token_swap# cp Cargo.toml Cargo.toml.bak
root@d51a1db5c2a8:/my_token_swap# vi Cargo.toml
root@d51a1db5c2a8:/my_token_swap# which rustc
/root/.cargo/bin/rustc
root@d51a1db5c2a8:/my_token_swap# anchor build
[2024-10-30T04:04:42.899468513Z ERROR cargo_build_sbf] Failed to obtain package metadata: `cargo metadata` exited with an error: error: failed to parse manifest at `/my_token_swap/Cargo.toml`
    
    Caused by:
      this virtual manifest specifies a `dependencies` section, which is not allowed
    
root@d51a1db5c2a8:/my_token_swap# cargo metadata
error: failed to parse manifest at `/my_token_swap/Cargo.toml`

Caused by:
  this virtual manifest specifies a `dependencies` section, which is not allowed



Be sure to update your Solana toolchain to the appropriate version. If you already have a toolchain installed, you can simply run:
solana-install init 1.18.26

So when you run cargo build-sbf, it will download the appropriate Solana compiler and use it.

Solana uses the rust version from the plattform tools which you can find in:
/Users/userName/.cache/solana
If you are using SPL token crate you can see here https://crates.io/crates/spl-token/6.0.0/dependencies that it needs Solana 2.0.0 So i think you need to update your installed solana version:
https://solana.com/de/docs/intro/installation

I've got the same error. But when I tried to install 1.18.26 and build with cargo as follows, it Worked!!:
solana-install init 1.18.26
cargo build-sbf

Many thanks!
